# Why actions in SveltKit give "Error: Cannot prerender pages with actions"?

Tags: javascript, vite, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit application, just following the example from the docs https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/named-form-actions, the problem is that everything works until I try to write an action:

at:  `+page.server.js`

```
export const actions = {
    default: async () => {
        console.log('test')
    }
};
```

vite immediately fails with:
"Cannot prerender pages with actions"

```
Error: Cannot prerender pages with actions
    at render_page (file:///mydir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/index.js:87:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async resolve (file:///mydir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:356:17)
    at async respond (file:///mydir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:229:20)
    at async file:///mydir/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:444:22
```

Probably I'm missing some configuration or forgot some basics, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender-when-not-to-prerender) simply state:

> Pages with actions cannot be prerendered, because a server must be able to handle the action POST requests.

The assumption is probably that a form action should have an effect on the page when submitted, which would not be possible when a static HTML page is served every time.

You could try to separate any logic to an API endpoint that is not associated with your prerendered page. It depends on what you are trying to do here, maybe the page should simply not be prerendered at all.

This means that `+page.ts` should set:

```js
export const prerender = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, i just missed to switch "export const prerender = false;" in +page.ts.